# Jenkins - Service fail to start on Windows 7

Tags: windows-services, jenkins

When I try manually to start Jenkins from "Computer Management" I got an error 1053: "Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion."

I try to start from CMD with: `jenkins.exe start`  and I get an error: 
[image]

The system was working some 2 weeks ago, I don't know what happened.

Comment: jenkins version? Java version?

Comment: Jenkins: <version>1.503</version> and Java: jre7

Comment: try latest version, but i think you have other problem. Try use not exe version. Use jar version.

Comment: The same configuration worked 2 weeks ago. I don't think the last version will help me

Comment: try this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839174

Comment: Thanks for your support, but I found the problem and I posted the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem, my server works very slow, probably because Windows. Windows can not start the Jenkins service in 30 seconds.

Solution:

The Service Control Manager will generate an event if a service does not respond within the defined timeout period (the default timeout period is 30000 milliseconds). To resolve this problem, use the Registry Editor to change the default timeout value for all services.

1. In the **Registry Editor**, click the registry subkey **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control**
2. In the details pane, locate the **ServicesPipeTimeout** entry, right-click that entry and then select **Modify.Note**: If the **ServicesPipeTimeout** entry does not exist, you must create it by selecting New on the Edit menu, followed by the **DWORD Value**, then typing **ServicesPipeTimeout**, and clicking Enter.
3. Click **Decimal**, enter the new timeout value in milliseconds (I prefer 120000), and then click **OK**.
4. Restart the computer.

Answer (score 1):

#### TL;DR:

If you're not getting any logs, maybe try running jenkins.exe at a command prompt and see if it provides something useful there.

#### Funny story:

I was having other issues with the Jenkins Windows service that required some changes to jenkins.xml and other places. I made those changes and the service started successfully. Yay! But while googling for that solution, I discovered some other changes I could make to jenkins.xml, so I made them. And for good measure added a couple comments regarding the changes.  Then the Jenkins Windows service wouldn't start again.  And suddenly there was *NOTHING* new in the logs at all.  Undid the configuration changes I had just made, and still got nothing.  Spent the rest of the day googling & tinkering unsuccessfully. Then I thought, "Hmm, why not just run jenkins.exe at a command prompt & see what happens."  Did that, and . . .

`The configuration file cound not be loaded. An XML comment cannot contain '--', and '-' cannot be the last character. Line 36, position 148.`

Good. Grief.

Comment: i met the same issue and i tried your method i got the same hint as yours "The configuration file cound not be loaded. An XML comment cannot contain '--', and '-' cannot be the last character. Line 41, position 117." then i check the jenkins.xml file i found line 41 was my backup comment   <!--arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments-->. then i deleted it and tried to start the  jenkins service again, it back to work. it seems it cannot parse this comment success. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Use task manager to check that there is not a hung instance of the service that is holding the listening TCP port open.

Are you using port 80, 8080 or something else?

Is it possible that IIS is installed on the machine and is stopping Jenkins from using the listening port?

Comment: Thank for your post. I checked the port 8080, it's not used, but for safety I set Jenkins on port 8070.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same error 1053. The jenkinsservice was not able to start.
 I noticed that port 8080 was already taken by other windows application service.
So i changed the port to other number in jenkins.xml in jenkins installation folder.
Now the jenkins service is up and running.